# how to prevent googlebot to indexing my sub-domains?

Tags: google-search

I am creating a flash game website for one of my client. consider this is my website:   www.website.com

I saved my all my SWF files in sub-domain like-> http://sub.website.com/game.swf.

But, the problem is Googlebot indexing my above SWF file link in google search. How to prevent that?

Comment: use robots.txt to disallow access

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a robots.txt file with the keyword `Disallow` and the subdomain.

See the [Google help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) on the topic.